# How to call repaint method using gesture detector "onTapUp"

Tags: flutter

I need to call the repaint method in custom painter onTapUp without using setstate method

Comment: what do you pass as a `Listenable repaint` property to [CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html) constructor?

Comment: i passed a ValueChange Notifier

Comment: class RectPainter extends CustomPainter {
 ValueNotifier<double> notifier;


 RectPainter(BuildContext context, this.notifier)
      : super(repaint: notifier);

Comment: so use `notifier.value++` for example - if you call it your painter will be kicked and will draw the new frame

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: yes it is working - i used that many times, for example [here](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/custom_painter_demo.dart#L49) - in this case instead of `double` it listens on `ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier;`

Comment: paint function is not calling onTapup. its calling only on hot reload.. Can u give example for onTapUp

Comment: it does not matter where you call it - it works everywhere - run the code i gave you and you will see how it works

Comment: didn't i say? it has to work...